# Is it possible to use TypeTag to instanciate a mixin type?

Tags: scala, reflection

Reusing https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499493/4936026, I wrote:

```
def newInstance[T: TypeTag]: T = {
  val tpe = typeOf[T]

  def fail = throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Cannot instantiate $tpe")

  val noArgConstructor = tpe.member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR) match {
    case symbol: TermSymbol =>
      symbol.alternatives.collectFirst {
        case constr: MethodSymbol if constr.paramLists == Nil || constr.paramLists == List(Nil) => constr
      } getOrElse fail

    case NoSymbol => fail
  }
  val classMirror = typeTag[T].mirror.reflectClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass)
  classMirror.reflectConstructor(noArgConstructor).apply().asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

But, it does not seem to work correctly with mixin types. Indeed, the following code:

```
class B { def m = 0 }

trait A extends B { override def m = super.m + 1 }

val x = newInstance[B with A]
```

produces (with code compiled using scala 2.11.7)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate B with A
```

Are mixin types not a part of the Scala type algebra?

Answer (score 0):

> Are mixin types not a part of the Scala type algebra?

Yes, they are. They just don't have constructors. When you write `new B with A` in code, you don't really instantiate `B with A`, but a new anonymous class created by the compiler which *does* have a constructor. Same would happen if you just tried to instantiate a trait without mixins involved.

Comment: OK, thanks. You are suggesting to use ClassTag instead  of TypeTag, aren't you?

Comment: No, `ClassTag` won't help. What you need is to somehow create the anonymous class the compiler normally creates for you at runtime, and it's far from trivial.